# How do I create addition function in javascript from one input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make JavaScript calculator. I want to create simple addition function in JavaScript but didn't know how to build that logic, need someone help, and in my code one input text field is present.

Code contain input buttons which is numbers now I need help. So how do I do addition function in JavaScript?

```js
function plus()
  {
      var textInputval=0;
      var textInputval1=2;
      var temp=0;
      textInputval = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
      textInputval1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('new').value);
      temp = textInputval + textInputval1;
      console.log(textInputval);
      console.log(textInputval1);
  }
```

```html
<div id = "cal-container">
    <form name="calculator">
      <input type="text" name="answer" value="" id="new">
      <br>
      <input type="button" value=" 1 " onclick="one()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 2 " onclick="two()" />
      <input type="button" value=" 3 " onclick="three()" />
      <input type="button" value=" + " onclick="plus()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: code link:- https://jsfiddle.net/archan/o9p3g1px/

Comment: Added the code from the jsfiddle mentioned in the comment section, from the author of the Post

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function action(method) {
          var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
          var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
          var result = null;

          switch (method) {
            case 'add':
              result = a + b;

              break;
            case 'subtract':
              result = a - b;
              break;
            case 'multiply':
              result = a * b;
              break;
            case 'divide':
              if (b != 0) {
                result = a / b;
              } else {
                alert('Can\'t divide by 0');

                return;
              }

              break;
          }

          if (result !== null) {

            document.getElementById("result").value = result;
          } else {

            document.getElementById("num1").value = "";
            document.getElementById("num2").value = "";
            document.getElementById("result").value = "";
          }
        }
```

```html
<span style="margin-right:1px">Number 1 </span>
<input id="num1" type="number"></br>
<span style="margin-right:5px">Number 2</span><input id="num2" type="number"></br>
<span style="margin-right:29px">Result</span><input id="result" type="number"> </br>


<button id="add" onclick="action('add')">+</button>
<button id="subtract" onclick="action('subtract')">-</button>
<button id="multiply" onclick="action('multiply')">*</button>
<button id="divide" onclick="action('divide')">/</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="action('clear')">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks But that's not satisfies me because i want to do with only one text-field and you have give me e.g with two text-fields. can you show me same e.g.- but only using one text-field (i'm building this for calculator)

Comment: mate it gives wrong output do this 
e.g:- 10*2/3*4+5*6+5 = 61.66666666666667 while the real answer is 195